# How to create slot machine win combinations in right way with jquery

Tags: jquery, combinations, slot

I am building a slot machine with fruits reels. I have 5 reels and 3 elements in each real. I have specific win combinations. See below the combinations

[image]

So now am trying to create the winning combinations when matched with jquery.

Here is the html markup

```
<div class="game_reel_first game_reel" id="first">
                                    <div class="game_reel_innerwrap">
                                        <div class="slot_item">
                                            <div class="slot_item_symbol"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slot_item">
                                            <div class="slot_item_symbol"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slot_item">
                                            <div class="slot_item_symbol"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slot_item">
                                            <div class="slot_item_symbol"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slot_item">
                                            <div class="slot_item_symbol"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slot_item">
                                            <div class="slot_item_symbol"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slot_item">
                                            <div class="slot_item_symbol"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slot_item">
                                            <div class="slot_item_symbol"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slot_item">
                                            <div class="slot_item_symbol"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slot_item">
                                            <div class="slot_item_symbol"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slot_item">
                                            <div class="slot_item_symbol"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

I have reel rotating animation which is getting 3 specific elements visible and adding corresponding classes.

So far what i did is

```
var topRowFirst = jQuery('#first .slot_item:nth-child(1) .slot_item_symbol').eq(0).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
    var topRowSecond = jQuery('#second .slot_item:nth-child(1) .slot_item_symbol').eq(0).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
    var topRowThird = jQuery('#third .slot_item:nth-child(1) .slot_item_symbol').eq(0).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
    var topRowFourth = jQuery('#fourth .slot_item:nth-child(1) .slot_item_symbol').eq(0).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
    var topRowFifth = jQuery('#fifth .slot_item:nth-child(1) .slot_item_symbol').eq(0).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
    if(topRowFirst === topRowSecond && topRowSecond === topRowThird && topRowThird === topRowFourth && topRowFourth === topRowFifth){
        alert('First row 5 elems');
        jQuery('.game_reel_combination').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).addClass('game_reel_combination_disabled');
            jQuery('.game_reel_combination_two').removeClass('game_reel_combination_disabled');
            jQuery('.game_reel_combination_two').addClass('game_reel_active_combination');
        });
    }
```

What is the easiest and right way of creating the winning combinations without odd lines of code?

Thanks.

Comment: use a matrix to save/get the states

Comment: Could you give me some example pls @madalinivascu?

Comment: you don't know what a matrix is ? its a 2 dimensional array

Comment: I haven't used so far but know what it is. I dont know how to create the save/get part per my code/structure/aniamtion @madalin ivascu.

Comment: you save the state by creating a array for each 9 state you have and then compare those with the state of the fields in your page, this is simple array manipulation

Comment: Yeah @madalinivascu I managed to create all the combinations with matrix and that was quite easy and short so thanks for the good suggestion.